# linear model of columns subset

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I am trying lm of a two subsetted column of a data.frame. here my example with mtcars. What's wrong? Thanks for the help

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(y=mtcars[c(1:10), "mpg"], x=mtcars[c(1:10), "cyl"]), colour="blue") +
  geom_smooth(aes(mtcars[c(1:10), "mpg"], mtcars[c(1:10), "cyl"]), method=lm, se=FALSE)
```

I get this error

```
Error in data.frame(x = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6), y = c(21, 21,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 32
```

Comment: *How* is it wrong? Does it not give the right results? Does it not work at all? Are the results slightly off? Give us some clues!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
ggplot(mtcars[1:10,]) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(y=mpg, x=cyl, colour="blue")) +
  stat_smooth(aes(y=mpg, x=cyl), method='lm', se=FALSE)
```

Basically, you since you 're using `ggplot(mtcars)` you just need to use the column names later on. Also, I think you meant to use `stat_smooth` instead of `geom_smooth`.

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am trying to plot only the first 10 rows of the two selected columns

Comment: I updated the answer. Just use `ggplot(mtcars[1:10,])` at the first line.